# How to continue a Docker container which has exited

Tags: docker

Consider:

```
docker run -it centos /bin/bash
```

I pressed <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**D**</kbd> to exit it.

I want to continue to run this container, but I found I can't.

The only method is

```
docker commit `docker ps -q -l` my_image
docker run -it my_image /bin/bash
```

Am I right? Is there a better method? (I'm using docker 0.8.0.)

Comment: Have you tried to assign a name to the container, and use that name to control it? By the way, by "exit it", you mean detach from it, right?

Comment: Docker *is* a tool for programming, at least that's how I use it. If the majority disagree, then someone should tell Docker to not point to StackOverflow as a place to ask questions. I'm sure this isn't the first "DevOps"-like question that could go either here or SuperUser.

Comment: Docker is a developer tool. It is already a 'docker' tag here. So, I think it is proper to ask in stackoverflow. I use it to build image which require build from clean environment.

Comment: I wish the folks who tagged this as "off-topic" would explain why!

Comment: To support this question as not being off-topic: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276579/210336 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271279/210336.

Comment: Stop reading `docker start -ai <container-id>` is the answers, accepted answer are ambiguous

Answer (score 433, accepted):

You can restart an existing container after it exited and your changes are still there.

```
docker start  `docker ps -q -l` # restart it in the background
docker attach `docker ps -q -l` # reattach the terminal & stdin
```

Comment: to brief as one line:

```docker start `docker ps -q -l` && docker attach `docker ps -q -l` ```

Comment: To brief as one line: `docker start -i $(docker ps -q -l)`. ;-) Naming can help to better control which container is selected. `-l` get the last, ok...

Comment: For those new to Linux, the `\`docker ps -q -l\`` bit is an expansion.  It will be replaced with the id of the last (-l) docker container created.  -q merely suppresses other info (bedsides the id) usually output by  `\`docker ps\``.  
----
_note:_  Backtick is not a quotation sign, it has a very special meaning. Everything you type between backticks is evaluated (executed) by the shell before the main command  
- http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-bash

Comment: I have found the container getting into a state called `Created...` from which it can not be started with a `docker start ...`.  It can however be restarted using `docker restart ...`

Comment: Note: `-l` only gets the "latest" docker. If you're like me and `docker ps -a` shows more than one thing that you need to start up, then you can restart "all" (-a) of them by changing the command above to `docker start  \`docker ps -q -a\``. `-q` just makes it "quiet" (not output logging).

Comment: How does it know which container you want to start?

Answer (score 205):

```
docker start -a -i `docker ps -q -l`
```

Explanation:

`docker start` start a container (requires name or ID)
`-a` attach to container
`-i` interactive mode
`docker ps` List containers 
`-q` list only container IDs
`-l` list only last created container

Comment: docker ps -q -l, It gives Container ID of last created one even if it is in start status.

Comment: what is the so-called "attach" to container?  The  "attach" ?

Comment: @skytree attach is for attaching your STDIO  **standard input and output** to that container that you are starting. Basically to send key strokes.

Comment: `unknown shorthand flag: 'q' in -q`

Answer (score 71):

Use:

```
docker start $(docker ps -a -q --filter "status=exited")
```

This will start all containers which are in the exited state.

```
docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash
```

This will connect to the particular container.

Comment: I found this was the only one that worked for me.. due to that crucial second line. `docker exec -it <container id> /bin/bash` (or just bash).

Comment: This worked for me, But i hade to run it two times since i had two containers. So if the first one starts and the second one gets an error. just hit the same command again and it should start the next container.

Answer (score 59):

If you want to do it in multiple, easy-to-remember commands:

1. list stopped containers:

`docker ps -a`

2. copy the name or the container id of the container you want to attach to, and start the container with:

`docker start -i <name/id>`

The `-i` flag tells docker to attach to the container's stdin.

If the container wasn't started with an interactive shell to connect to, you need to do this to run a shell:

```
docker start <name/id>
docker exec -it <name/id> /bin/sh
```

The `/bin/sh` is the shell usually available with alpine-based images.

If you're having problems with the container exiting immediately when you start it above, you can re-run it with an interactive shell with the following.  You need the name of the image here,
not the container. Because restarting didn't work, the only way to debug the problem is to delete and run it again. You are put into a shell, where you can try the CMD from the Dockerfile to see its output, or to debug why it is exiting immediately.

```
docker rm <name/id>
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh <image-name> -s
```

Comment: Underrated answer, this helped me find the container i was looking for much easier than the "answer" on this question.

Comment: `Error response from daemon: Container <id> is not running`

Comment: @Cerin, I have added a last section for your problem (only 3 years late!), where the container exits immediately after you start it.

Comment: this answer is better than others because it breaks down what the command means

Answer (score 20):

If you want to continue exactly one Docker container with a known name:

```
docker start  `docker ps -a -q --filter "name=elas"`
```

Comment: thanks @Nelson
this is very helpful for me to start particular docker

Comment: In this case you can just run `docker start <name>` where <name> is the name of your container. At least with docker v19.03.8

Answer (score 17):

Follow these steps:

1. Run below command to see that all the container services both running and stopped on. Option `-a` is given to see that the container stops as well

   ```
   docker ps -a
   ```
2. Then start the docker container either by `container_id` or container tag names

   ```
   docker start <CONTAINER_ID> or <NAMES>
   ```

   [image]

   Say from the above picture, container id 
   4b161b302337
   So command to be run is

   ```
   docker start 4b161b302337
   ```
3. One can verify whether the container is running with

   ```
   docker ps
   ```

Answer (score 13):

If you have a named container then it can be started by running

```
docker container start container_name
```

where **container_name** is name of the container that must be given at the time of creating container. You can replace `container_name` with the container id in case the container is not named. The container ID can be found by running:

```
docker ps -a
```

Answer (score 9):

These commands will work for any container (not only last exited ones).
This way will work even after your system has rebooted.
To do so, these commands will use "container id".

Steps:

1. List all containers by using this command and note the container id of the container you want to restart:
   `docker ps -a`
2. Start your container using container id:
   `docker start <container_id>`
3. Attach and run your container:
   `docker attach <container_id>`

NOTE: Works on linux

Answer (score 3):

by name

```
sudo docker start bob_the_container
```

or by Id

```
sudo docker start aa3f365f0f4e
```

this restarts stopped container, use -i to attach container's STDIN
or instead of -i you can attach to container session (if you run with -it)

```
sudo docker attach bob_the_container
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to start a container with status 'Exited', just type:

```
sudo docker start container_name
```

Without sudo. [See more](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user)

```
docker start container_name
```

If container name doesn't work, replace the name to container id

Answer (score 2):

Run your container with --privileged flag.

```
docker run -it --privileged ...
```

Comment: Good find. the --privileged option seems to keep the container around after the original run exits. Also helps to have "--name myName"  so "docker start ..." and "docker exec ..." commands work.

Answer (score 2):

Steps are below to check and resume your exited containers

1. Run below command to see that all the container services both running and stopped on. Option `-a` is given to see that the container stops as well

   ```
    docker ps -a
   ```
2. Then start the docker container either by `container_id` or container tag names

   ```
    docker start <CONTAINER_ID> or <NAMES>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker start `docker ps -a | awk '{print $1}'`
```

This will start up all the containers that are in the 'Exited' state

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here in 2021 and beyond, the following command will do what the accepted answer will do in one line.

```sh
$ docker start -ai $(docker ps -q -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the docker container exits cleanly when I start it so none of the above worked. What I needed was a way to change the command to be run.

With docker-compose I was able to change the command by running:

```
docker-compose run <container name in docker-compose.yml> bash
```

e.g.

```
docker-compose run app bash
```

Note! This actually recreates the container, so it is not run on the previous instance.

Answer (score -1):

for me, I was testing **node version** which was not working. So I tried below command

```
docker run -d -it node:latest
```