# What's the difference between "docker stop" and "docker rm"?

Tags: docker

I initially thought that `docker stop` is equivalent to `vagrant halt`, and `docker rm` is to `vagrant destroy`.

But fundamentally, docker containers are stateless, except for `VOLUME` statement, which AFAIK preserves directory content even after `docker rm`, if it wasn't called with `-v`.

So, what is the difference?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

[`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) preserves the container in the [`docker ps -a`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) list (which gives the opportunity to commit it if you want to save its state in a new image).

It sends SIGTERM first, then, after a grace period, SIGKILL.

[`docker rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/) will remove the container from `docker ps -a` list, losing its "state" (the layered filesystems written on top of the image filesystem). It cannot remove a *running* container (unless called with `-f`, in which case it sends SIGKILL directly).

In term of lifecycle, you are supposed to stop the container first, then remove it. It gives a chance to the [container PID 1 to collect zombie processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119321/6309).

Comment: Do I lose container state if I run `docker stop`, then `docker start`? I thought I do.

Comment: @mkurnikov from http://stackoverflow.com/a/21928864/6309, you don't lose your changes.

Comment: Ok, so this commands _are_ equivalent to `vagrant` commands after all.

Comment: Some may also find helpful: `docker rmi <name>` will remove the image (from which the container was created from)

Comment: after successfully doing both: `docker stop some-postgress` and  `docker rm some-postgress`, where some-postgress is the name of my postgress db, i can still see the container in `docker ps -a`. i think this is the case because you might have referenced the images rather than given container names.

Comment: @moldovean In which state that container is? Exited?

Comment: Is it same with podman stop ?

Comment: @ShivamPapat it should, even though there is a bug for containers started with `--rm` as an option: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/11384

Answer (score 6):

`docker rm` removes the container image from your storage location (e.g. debian: /var/lib/docker/containers/) whereas
`docker stop` simply halts the the container.

Comment: I have tried running `docker images | grep container_name` before and then after running `docker rm -f container_name` and I got the same one_line output. So, it only stops the container; this does not remove the image used to run the container. Or am I getting something wrong?