# How to start the container in Docker in my case

Tags: python, docker, docker-container

I am trying to setup my python environment in docker.

My docker image is like this:

```
FROM python:2.7
# updating repository
RUN apt-get update

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8888

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

with this build command:

```
docker build -t ml-python-2.7 .
```

After image is built, 
I ran

```
docker run -it --name ml-container -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app ml-python-2.7 python test.py
```

My sample `test.py`

```
print('test here')
```

It works when I first run this command and update the output every time I changed my test.py

The problem is if I want to keep the container and remove the `--rm` option, the container quit and I can't run

```
docker run -it --name ml-container -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app ml-python-2.7 python test.py
```

anymore because it says there is a container name conflict. How do I keep the container and run the test.py again after that file is updated? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After the container has exited, you can start it again using `docker start`.  More information here: [How to continue a docker which is exited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928691/how-to-continue-a-docker-which-is-exited)