# docker: data volumes container

Tags: docker

So I'm still trying to figure out what would be the best way to use docker in my current infrastructure.

I've been thinking of creating a data-volume containers, that containers would hold the data volume for mongodb (this seem to be pretty popular approach).

If I do that, how would I update the container without loosing the data inside it?

========== EDIT ==========

Clarification:
I want to be able to "update" the container by, basically, rebuilding from `Dockerfile`. This means that I'll need to spin up a new container, but I want to keep the volumes from the old one

Comment: You can commit the container to save it's data.  use `docker commit`  see this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585028/docker-i-lose-my-data-when-the-container-exits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might help you:

https://github.com/discordianfish/docker-backup

TL;DR: You just need to ensure that another container (such as: backup_monitor) is referencing the data volume and you will keep the volumes no matter what. Whether you rebuild  your container or not, data volumes are meant to bypass the Union File System so it are kept while there is some container pointing to it.
Another approach could be to share the data volumes with the docker host, using this way you can forget about data because is saved on the host directly. Hope it helps.