# Get Docker container id from container name

Tags: docker

What is the command to get the Docker container **id** from the container **name**?

Comment: You should read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. How does `docker --list` or similar look like? What is the command to create a new container? etc

Comment: There is no such thing as a "container" that I know of in bash. Perhaps you mean *docker* containers? If so, people watching the "bash" tag might get confused. however you get the container id from the name, I'm sure it is an actual command and has nothing to do with the bash programming language.

Answer (score 351, accepted):

In Linux:

```
sudo docker ps -aqf "name=containername"
```

Or in OS X, Windows:

```
docker ps -aqf "name=containername"
```

where `containername` is your container name.

To avoid getting false positives, as @llia Sidorenko notes, you can use regex anchors like so:

```
docker ps -aqf "name=^containername$"
```

explanation:

- `-q` for quiet. output only the ID
- `-a` for all. works even if your container is not running
- `-f` for [filter](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/).
- `^` container name must *start* with this string
- `$` container name must *end* with this string

Comment: a note to anyone who stumbles upon this: sudo is no longer required on linux if you [add yourself to the docker group](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/create-a-docker-group) (highly recommended)

Comment: Please be careful with this answer, as name=containername is actually a wildcard and it will match anything with name (.*)containername(.*)

Comment: that seems to generate a short id.  if I look in /var/lib/docker/containers I see long ids.  how to get the long id?

Comment: @ekkis use the `--no-trunc` flag. so `docker ps --no-trunc -aqf "name=containername"`

Comment: As of 2019-01-07, this did not work for me.  I'm using docker v17.06.0.  The command ```docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" imageName``` worked for me.

Comment: @PatS 's way is the new best way. Docker API evolves quickly

Comment: @code_monk, Thanks for the confirmation.   I've added a comment to Rosberg Linhares answer which is where I got the idea from, and suggested his answer be changed to the correct answer.

Comment: The regex anchors version doesn't work for me (no match). I resorted to using awk: ` docker ps | awk '$2 ~ /^your-image-name$/ { print $1 }'`

Comment: This helped me tremendously thank you. I want to add that if you want to find the running IMAGE name instead, try this `docker ps -qf "ancestor=containername"` where containername is the full name like `searx\searx`

Answer (score 71):

You can try this:

```
docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" container_name
```

This approach is OS independent.

Comment: This returns IMAGE ID NOT CONTAINER ID

Comment: @vijay, for me this gives the container ID: [https://i.ibb.co/BPwyxDj/Docker-Container-Id.png](https://i.ibb.co/BPwyxDj/Docker-Container-Id.png)

Comment: This also gives me the container ID.  The full container ID, not just the truncated first 12 characters.

Comment: Love this one! Thanks. 

Comment: @vijay @RosbergLinhares if you provide the name of the container (given in the `NAMES` column with `docker ps`), it gives the container ID. If the image name (given in the `IMAGE` column with `docker ps`) is provided instead, it outputs the image ID instead.

Comment: If you want to avoid the ambiguity between image and container names, you can use `docker container inspect --format="{{.Id}}" container_name` instead. This will only return container IDs and say `Error: No such container: name` otherwise.

Comment: A followup to the answer by DarioSeidl, you can aslo use `docker inspect --type=container --format="{{.Id}}" container_name` to restrict the search to only containers.

Answer (score 24):

You could use the following command to print the container id:

```
docker container ls  | grep 'container-name' | awk '{print $1}'
```

As a bonus point, if you want to login to the container with a container name:

```
docker exec -it $(docker container ls  | grep 'container-name' | awk '{print $1}') /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 16):

1. Get container Ids of running containers ::

   ```
   $docker ps -qf "name=IMAGE_NAME"

       -f: Filter output based on conditions provided
       -q: Only display numeric container IDs
   ```
2. Get container Ids of all containers ::

   ```
   $docker ps -aqf "name=IMAGE_NAME"

       -a: all containers
   ```

Comment: `docker ps -fq ` did not work however `docker ps -qf` did (order of flags)

Answer (score 14):

The following command:

```
docker ps --format 'CONTAINER ID : {{.ID}} | Name: {{.Names}} | Image:  {{.Image}} |  Ports: {{.Ports}}'
```

**Gives this output:**

```
CONTAINER ID : d8453812a556 | Name: peer0.ORG2.ac.ae | Image:  hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.4 |  Ports: 0.0.0.0:27051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27053->7053/tcp
CONTAINER ID : d11bdaf8e7a0 | Name: peer0.ORG1.ac.ae | Image:  hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.4 |  Ports: 0.0.0.0:17051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:17053->7053/tcp
CONTAINER ID : b521f48a3cf4 | Name: couchdb1 | Image:  hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:0.4.15 |  Ports: 4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5985->5984/tcp
CONTAINER ID : 14436927aff7 | Name: ca.ORG1.ac.ae | Image:  hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.4 |  Ports: 0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp
CONTAINER ID : 9958e9f860cb | Name: couchdb | Image:  hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:0.4.15 |  Ports: 4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp
CONTAINER ID : 107466b8b1cd | Name: ca.ORG2.ac.ae | Image:  hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.4 |  Ports: 0.0.0.0:7055->7054/tcp
CONTAINER ID : 882aa0101af2 | Name: orderer1.o1.ac.ae | Image:  hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.4 |  Ports: 0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get complete ContainerId based on Container name then use following command

```
 docker ps --no-trunc -aqf name=containername
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was running Tensorflow Docker container in Ubuntu 20.04 :Run your docker container in One terminal , I ran it with

```
docker run -it od
```

And then started another terminal and ran below `docker ps` with sudo:

```
sudo docker ps
```

I successfully got container id:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             
STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
e4ca1ad20b84        od                  "/bin/bash"         18 minutes ago      
Up 18 minutes                           unruffled_stonebraker
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/65513726/889126, it gave me an idea to make a complete bash script as it is

```
export api_image_id=$(docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" <image-name> | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d')

sudo docker exec -i -t ${api_image_id} /bin/bash
```

I need a specific container and make a script to extract some info from it in a quick sight.

Hope this would help others.

Answer (score 1):

To have container id and image Id -

```sh
$ docker container ls -a | awk 'NR>1 {print $1, $2}'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This just gives ids and names list, doesn't answer the question. imagine you have 100 containers running and this will not be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I tried `sudo docker container stats`, and it will give out Container ID along with details of memory usage and Name, etc. If you want to stop viewing the process, do `Ctrl+C`. I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I also need the container name or Id which a script requires to attach to the container.
took some tweaking but this works perfectly well for me...

```
export svr=$(docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}"| sed 's/CONTAINER ID//g' | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d')
docker exec -it $svr bash
```

The sed command is needed to get rid of the fact that the words CONTAINER ID gets printed too ... but I just need the actual id stored in a var.

Answer (score 0):

To get the ID of a Docker container, you can use the **docker ps -a** , which lists all containers, including stopped ones.

Answer (score -2):

Docker image inspect ImageName\ImageId --format={{'.ConatinerConfig.Hostname'}}

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer. Answers that are code only (or in this case command only) are not helpful to new users who might not understand what the command or code actually does. Look up cargo cult programming for why this is bad.

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way I can think of is to parse the output of `docker ps`

Let's run the latest ubuntu image interactively and connect to it

```
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

If you run `docker ps` in another terminal you can see something like

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
8fddbcbb101c        ubuntu:latest       "/bin/bash"         10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes                           gloomy_pasteur
```

Unfortunately, parsing this format isn't easy since they uses spaces to manually align stuff

```
$ sudo docker ps | sed -e 's/ /@/g'
CONTAINER@ID@@@@@@@@IMAGE@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@COMMAND@@@@@@@@@@@@@CREATED@@@@@@@@@@@@@STATUS@@@@@@@@@@@@@@PORTS@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@NAMES
8fddbcbb101c@@@@@@@@ubuntu:latest@@@@@@@"/bin/bash"@@@@@@@@@13@minutes@ago@@@@@@Up@13@minutes@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@gloomy_pasteur@@@@@@
```

Here is a script that converts the output to JSON.

https://gist.github.com/mminer/a08566f13ef687c17b39

Actually, the output is a bit more convenient to work with than that. Every field is 20 characters wide.
`[['CONTAINER ID',0],['IMAGE',20],['COMMAND',40],['CREATED',60],['STATUS',80],['PORTS',100],['NAMES',120]]`