# How to obtain container id base on docker image name via command line ?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, unix, docker-container

If I ran `sudo doccker ps` I got this

```
[user@vm1 ~]$ sudo docker ps 

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED                  STATUS                  PORTS                        NAMES
e8ff73dec1d5        portal-mhn:latest         "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   43 minutes ago           Up 43 minutes  portal-mhn_portal-mhn.1.4rsfv94wy97gb333q3kfyxz32
62a7cf09d7bf        portal-admin:latest       "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   43 minutes ago           Up 43 minutes  portal-admin_portal-admin.1.s62iep4gl5g5oj2hrap14kz1t
```

I'm trying to grab the container ID base on ImageName.

Ex. Is there away to grab the container id of portal-mhn:latest via a command line ? which is `e8ff73dec1d5`

Comment: Filter by IMAGE name  `sudo docker ps -aqf "ancestor=portal-mhn:latest "` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496882/get-docker-container-id-from-container-name

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to get the container id based on the image name this should work:

```
$ docker ps | grep '<image_name>' | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Or even:

```
$ docker ps | awk '/<image_name>/ { print $1 }'
```

As others have suggested you can also directly filter by the image name using the `ancestor` filter:

```
$ docker ps -aqf "ancestor=<image_name>"
```

Thanks to @kevin-cui and @yu-chen.

Comment: Thank you. Work perfect

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer works, but you might possibly have a misnamed container name that has `postgres` in its name but is actually running a totally different image, since the answer only uses `grep` to look for matching lines.

You can use Docker's built in `filter` flag:

```sh
docker ps --filter "ancestor=postgres" -q
```

as an alternative. The `-q` flag indicates to only return the container ID (quiet mode).

Answer (score 1):

I needed only to obtain the latest running container id by image name, including stopped containers:

```
docker ps -a | grep 'django-content-services:' -m 1 | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

In docker `-a` to include all containers (even stopped). In grep, `-m` so grep only matches the first case. Cheers!