# Calling docker-container by name - making commands (docker exec) to it specifically

Tags: bash, docker, awk, docker-compose, makefile

I have a `docker-compose.yaml`-file, that spins up a couple of containers: `nginx`, `php`, `mysql`.

I'm trying to automate a setup-process, that imports a database to the `mysql`-container, as part of a make-target.

The make-target looks like this:

```
startLocalEnv:
    docker-compose up -d # Build containers
    # A lot of other stuff happens here, that is omitted to keep it simple

importDb:
    # THIS IS THE COMMAND I'M TRYING TO MAKE
    docker exec -i CONTAINER_ID mysql -usomeuser -psomepassword local_db_name < ./dumps/existingDbDump.sql
```

How can I make this command: `docker exec -i CONTAINER_ID mysql -usomeuser -psomepassword local_db_name < ./dumps/existingDbDump.sql`
so that it doesn't become several steps, copying and pasting?

### Currently

This is how it's done today:

**Step 1:** Do a `docker ps` and copy the Container ID. Let's say: `41e8203b54ea`.

**Step 2:** Insert that into above-written command and run it. Example: `docker exec -i 41e8203b54ea mysql -usomeuser -psomepassword local_db_name < ./dumps/existingDbDump.sql`

It's not super painful, but it's something quite rudimentary, that I'm assuming (and hoping) can be made into one step fairly easily.

### Solution attempt 1: Pipe the shit out of it!

I found this SO-article here: [Get Docker container id from container name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496882/get-docker-container-id-from-container-name). Where I found this to output the Container ID: `docker container ls  | grep mysql | awk '{print $1}'`.

So I imagine, that fiddling around with this, that maybe I can get a one-liner, that runs this import.

But it seems excessive. And if I have another project that also has a container called `mysql` (fairly possible!), that I have forgotten to stop, then this solution will target that.

Comment: You can use a static docker process name instead of `CONTAINER_ID` that changes every time.

Comment: @anubhava - That sounds smart! Do you have a link to a place where I can read on how to do that? If I search for `how to use static docker process`, then I get a lot about how to assign static IP's to docker containers.

Comment: Just use `--name=mysqldb` in `docker run` command

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`docker-compose exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_exec/) command that will automatically do this lookup for you.

```
importDb: ./dumps/existingDbDump.sql
        docker-compose exec mysql mysql -usomeuser -psomepassword local_db_name < $<
```

This would probably be my third-choice way to do the database load, though.  If you have the `mysql` CLI tool on your host and your database container has published `ports:` then you can just run that directly, without doing anything Docker-specific.

```
importDb: ./dumps/existingDbDump.sql
        mysql -h127.0.0.1 -usomeuser -psomepassword local_db_name < $<
```

Or you can [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/) a temporary container to do the load:

```
importDb: ./dumps/existingDbDump.sql
        docker-compose run mysql \
            mysql -hmysql -usomeuser -psomepassword local_db_name < $<
```

If your application framework has a database migration system, you could similarly `docker-compose run` the migrations.