# get the container ID of an image

Tags: docker

What command do I run to get the container ID of an image?

I would think docker ps -a something...

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                              NAMES
17ef697da46d   local_django         "/entrypoint /start"     56 minutes ago   Up 56 minutes             0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp             django-1
```

I only want the container ID returned from an image search

Comment: Try this  docker ps -aqf "name=local_django"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496882/get-docker-container-id-from-container-name

Comment: It doesn't return?

➜  ~  docker ps -aqf "name=local_django"
➜  ~

Comment: For me is working, you can also try the docker inspect as it's written in the answer

Comment: (You can launch multiple containers from an image, or none, so this may not have a single answer.  If you know the container name then you can directly use that with CLI tools without looking up the hex container ID.)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `-q` option to only get the ID back. And the `-f` option to filter on 'ancestor' which means the image name or any image in the chain of images it's based on.

```
ps -aqf ancestor=local_django
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on image

```
docker ps -aqf ancestor=<image_name>
```

You can get it based on name as well

```
docker ps -aqf name=<container_name>
```

Also to get all container ids

```
docker ps -q
```