# save installations at Docker

Tags: docker

I am using Docker machine for a project, but I cannot find a way to save my installations(eg when I install libraries like numpy,pandas etc). Every time that I switch off my laptop and hence the Docker machine I lose them. I tried the following: docker-machine restart dev, from https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/restart/ ,but still doesn't work. Is there a way to keep the installations and avoid installing them every time I turn on the laptop?

Thx in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585028/i-lose-my-data-when-the-container-exits might help

Answer (score 1):

They should still be there unless you are removing them when you shut down your machine.

If you do a `docker-machine ls` it will show you the machines you have installed, if you see one you like you can

```
docker-machine start <name>
```

Once started you need to set your env variables

```
docker-machine env <name>
```

And copy the variables into your shell or eval them

```
eval $(docker-machine env <name>)
```

Now that you are linked to the machine you can see all of your running containers

```
docker ps
```

Or to see all even the ones that are stopped

```
docker ps -a
```

My guess is that your containers have stopped and you just need to start them again. If you set the [restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart) correctly on container create they will restart automatically when the machine restarts

Comment: it seems that I might do something wrong with the policies because the commands that you proposed don't work..

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what doesn't work? Are they giving errors? Are you not seeing any containers when you run `docker ps -a` or any machines when you run `docker-machine ls` ?

Comment: Can you add that to your question, it is hard to read in the comments. Do you have docker and docker-machine installed on the machine you are running the commands on?

Comment: I am trying the following "project": (https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/)  and when I try the commands that you said that's what I get:
bash:                                                                                                       docker: command not found
root@a825d6a1a3dc:/# docker-machine ls
bash: docker-machine: command not found.                                              Sorry could be really silly, but I am totally new at the field.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have docker or docker-machine installed on that machine. How did you install them?