# Docker container crash - how to retain settings?

Tags: docker, jenkins

When a docker container crashes and I make a new one, how can I ensure I have the settings from the last one in place? The container I am running contains Jenkins only.

Comment: See if this is what you are looking for ? https://engineering.riotgames.com/news/docker-jenkins-data-persists

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19585028/1531971

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a volume if you want your configuration changes to be persisted.

In the image I am using as a base (usually `jenkins/jenkins:2.75-alpine`), the configuration lives under: `/var/jenkins_home/workspace`

so all I need to do is something like:

```
docker run -v /path/on/host:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:2.75-alpine
```