# The container exited with status code (1)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I encountered an issue when running the docker container.
An error log was generated as below:

[Error] mysqld : unknown variable “wait_timeout = 288000”.

I wanted to test some docker container features.
So, I opened the docker bash and entered the directory /etc/mysql/my.cnf.
And I added the variable “wait_timeout = 288000” below [mysqld] option.

However, after rebooting, when I ran the container, it exited immediately with status code (1).
I knew that the error was caused by the variable I just added.
So, I wanted to delete the variable, but now the docker container bash won’t open.
Is there any way that I can delete the variable “wait_timeout” in this case?
If there isn’t, could you recommend other methods for troubleshooting?
Thanks for checking the issue.

Comment: You should share the contents of your Dockerfile, or the docker pull and docker run commands you're using.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798910/saving-configuration-on-docker-container

Answer (score 0):

Delete and recreate the container, and it will start fresh from a clean container filesystem.

That is probably also a better way to modify the database configuration (if you do, in fact, need a custom `my.cnf`).  You can bind-mount a directory of configuration files into the container at startup time:

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mysql \
  -v $PWD/mysql-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d \
  mysql:8
```

Then when the configuration changes, you can delete and recreate this container:

```
docker stop mysql
docker rm mysql
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 ... mysql:8 # as above
```

(See "Using a custom MySQL configuration file" in the [Docker Hub `mysql` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) for more information.)

Deleting and recreating Docker containers is very routine, and one of the benefits is that when a new container starts, it always has a "clean" filesystem.  This particular setup also makes sure the modified configuration file is stored outside the container, so if you are forced to recreate the container (to upgrade MySQL to get a critical security fix, for example) it's something you're used to doing and you won't lose data or settings.

Comment: thanks for your comment :) really helpful!