# Running container can't find the file that it has created to /home/user/ directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I hope you are having a great day!

I'm new to docker. I think my problem is related to `docker's directory tree`

My app writes to a file to `/home/user` directory and  then after some time reads that file again.

I got this error from my app.

```
[error] a.a.OneForOneStrategy - /home/user/bkjw_eqvfohygvkaxoxc-small.jpg
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/user/bkjw_eqvfohygvkaxoxc-small.jpg
```

My dockerized app is unable to create the file and read. I'm thinking that the Docker considers the directory `/home/user/` as a absolute directory of host. 
I thought that the container would write to `/home/user` directory within the container's directory tree.

So the question is :

**How can I specify the path to write the file inside the containers directory tree?**

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile and the docker build logs, so that I can find out where is the issue?

Comment: Since you are new to Docker, you might be using `docker run` not properly, like this guy here: [I lose my data when the container exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585028/i-lose-my-data-when-the-container-exits)

Comment: How you are copying the file. Share your docker, then simple to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding about the directory tree is correct. Application running inside a docker container would write to `/home/user/` in the container's directory tree.

Your issue seems to be with permissions, your java application probably doesn't have the rights to write to `/home/user/` within the container. Either you should change the ownership/rights of the directory you're wanting to write in, or a simple solution I did in such case was to create the directory I wanted to write in, within the java code.

like:

```
// Create volume directories explicitly so that they are created with correct owner
Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(dirPath));
```

You can set `dirPath` String to something like `/home/user/mydir` IF your requirement is not to write in `/home/user/` specifically.

Comment: As long as container is running, I should be able to access by console this created directory right? Could you tell me where it is located? The files of containers seems to be reside in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/`, is it correct?