# Can Docker Containers maintain state between restarts?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, docker

Should containers be able to maintain state? 
I am using a SQLServer Image like so.

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password' -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

Then I create a database in it using dotnet ef.

```
dotnet ef database update -v
```

Database works fine until I restart the container. At which point my database is gona and the container is reset to it's initial state.

What am I missing? Do containers not persist state?
If so what's the point in using them for databases?

Comment: How do you "restart"? Which command do you use?

Comment: docker stop 'container id'

Comment: After that do you use `docker run ...` or `docker start ...`?

Comment: docker run ....

Comment: You are doing the same mistake with this guy here: [I lose my data when the container exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585028/i-lose-my-data-when-the-container-exits)

Comment: `docker run ...` creates and starts a new container. `docker start ...` starts a stopped container.

Comment: Doh! Thanks. Glad to here I don't need to create special persistent volumes as my research started to indicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I lose my data when the container exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585028/i-lose-my-data-when-the-container-exits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they can if you don not delete the container so you can

```
docker stop xxx
```

or just simply restart your machine and than use

```
docker start xxx
```

or

```
docker restart xxx
```

if you use `docker run` you create a new container so there is no previous state to talk about. For sql server specifically there is an option to create a volume and store data there. If you do that you can delete a container and recreate it again without loosing data as its is no longer stored inside it.