# How to restart Oracle WebLogic on Docker containers

Tags: docker, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm using [official WebLogic images](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleWebLogic) to run the domain in Docker containers. In the development environment I have to experiment with settings, which requires the WebLogic to be restarted. However, stopping the admin server will also stop the container and all the data will be lost. How to come around with this?

Seems like my only painful choice is to experiment with the settings is in the build phase WLST scripts.

Comment: "Store the data outside the container" is the usual answer to this; either in a database or a `docker run -v` host directory.

Comment: Check also if you are doing the mistake described here: [I lose my data when the container exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585028/i-lose-my-data-when-the-container-exits)