# Restoration of Hdfs files

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hdfs

We have a spark cluster which is built with the help of docker(singularities/spark image). When we remove containers, data which is stored in hdfs is removed. It is normal I know, but how can I solve the problem such that  whenever I start cluster again, files in hdfs restore without upload again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I lose my data when the container exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585028/i-lose-my-data-when-the-container-exits)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind/mount a host volume as below for `/opt/hdfs` directory for both master & worker -

```
version: "2"

services:
  master:
    image: singularities/spark
    command: start-spark master
    hostname: master
    volumes:
      - "${PWD}/hdfs:/opt/hdfs"
    ports:
      - "6066:6066"
      - "7070:7070"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50070:50070"
  worker:
    image: singularities/spark
    command: start-spark worker master
    volumes:
      - "${PWD}/hdfs:/opt/hdfs"
    environment:
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 1
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 2g
    links:
      - master
```

This way your HDFS files will always persist at `./hdfs`(`hdfs` in current working directory) on the host machine.

Ref - https://hub.docker.com/r/singularities/spark/