# Why doesn't Docker container save when exit?

Tags: docker

Why Docker is designed that way? I can only think of only one reason: to avoid these 2 errors:

- Repeated restart
- Partial error

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585028/i-lose-my-data-when-the-container-exits) is perhaps one of the most-read answers for a newbie like me about this behavior when a container "exits". However, it doesn't explain the why.

Comment: "Immutable infrastructure" is the more general concept.  You will always need to be able to install and start things from a blank slate; making that the _only_ way to do things saves trouble and potential inconsistencies from also needing to build an upgrade path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running containers correctly, there is nothing inside the container you want to keep. It should be noted that only tmpfs mounts are deleted on *exit* of a container. Other changes to the container filesystem are deleted when the container is *removed*. By replacing containers with new instances, going back to the initial image state, we force changes to go into code that builds the image and remove the management of state drift.

Looking at the various types of things that could be lost, here is where you should be saving those changes:

- **Data**: any persistent data should be saved in a volume.
- **Application code and dependencies**: these should be stored inside the image itself, built with a Dockerfile, and the container replaced with a new container running from the new image.
- **Configuration files**: these can be mounted as single file volumes, read only, and managed on the host. Or with swarm mode, secrets and configs can be injected as files in the container using secret and config objects.
- **Temporary files**: by their very definition are temporary and should not be saved. You can use a tmpfs mount for these to have them stored in ram.
- **Log files**: These should be written to stdout/stderr, and not into the container. Docker will capture these streams with your selected log driver. For persistence, these logs should be centralized with a tool like Elastic.