# Docker container file getting lost after I stop the container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I pulled Ubuntu image using `docker pull`.

I connect to the container using `docker exec` and then create a file and then exit.

Again, when I execute docker exec file is lost.

How to maintain the file in that container, I have tried dockerfile and tagging docker images, it works.

But, is there any other way to maintain the files in docker container for a longer time?

Comment: Check if you are doing the mistake described here: [I lose my data when the container exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585028/i-lose-my-data-when-the-container-exits) by using `docker run ...` instead of `docker start ...`.

Comment: While the top-voted answer to that question is `docker commit`, I don't usually consider that a best practice.  Better is to write a Dockerfile that includes the commands you need to run to install the software or create the files, check that into source control, and have a reproducible way to `docker build` an image.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to [commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) your changes. After you've added the file, and while the container is still running, you should run:

```
docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
```

Another option, maybe you'll want to use a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), but that depends on your logic and needs.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to persist content in containers its with [Docker Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/):

```
╭─exadra37@exadra37-Vostro-470 ~/Developer/DevNull/stackoverflow  
╰─➤  sudo docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/data ubuntu 

root@00af7ccf1d3b:/# echo "Persits data with Docker Volumes" > /data/docker-volumes.txt

root@00af7ccf1d3b:/# cat /data/docker-volumes.txt 
Persits data with Docker Volumes

root@00af7ccf1d3b:/# exit

╭─exadra37@exadra37-Vostro-470 ~/Developer/DevNull/stackoverflow  
╰─➤  ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 exadra37 exadra37 4096 Nov 25 15:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 exadra37 exadra37 4096 Nov 25 15:33 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       33 Nov 25 15:34 docker-volumes.txt

╭─exadra37@exadra37-Vostro-470 ~/Developer/DevNull/stackoverflow  
╰─➤  cat docker-volumes.txt                                                                                                                                                                                  
Persits data with Docker Volumes
```

#### The docker command explained:

```
sudo docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/data alpine
```

- I used the flag `-v` to map the current dir `$PWD` to the `/data` dir inside the container
- inside the container:

  - I wrote some content to it
  - I read that same content
  - I exited the container
- On the host:

  - I used `ls -al` to confirm that the file was persisted to my computer.
  - I confirmed could access that same file in my computer filesystem.