# Docker -v command wipes the container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am creating a docker container that will run a minecraft server. (Yes i know, these already exist). And of course i want the world to be saved when the container is turned off.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java 
COPY ./ /home
CMD ["java","-jar","/home/main.jar"]
EXPOSE 25565
```

Then i build the container:

`docker build -t minecraftdev .`

Run the container:

`docker run -dp 25565:25565 -v C:/Users/user/server:/home minecraftdev`

And then the files in the image, server.properies, the server jar file and EULA.txt is wiped.

Is there another way i don't now of to get the container to store data? And this is without placing the files in the server folder.

Comment: The `-v` option replaces _everything_ in the container `/home` directory with the host-directory content, even the jar file in the image.  You need to restructure or reconfigure your application to store its data somewhere different from the directory with the jar file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585028/i-lose-my-data-when-the-container-exits

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, i was able to fix it by `-v C:/Users/user/server/world:/home/world` As the world files are stored in that folder, Instead of changing out all the files in the folder as i didn't know -v did.

Minecraft makes the server.jar file and i don't know how to change so it stores all the files in another place.